# Jenkins Groovy post-build script to evaluate file with function

Tags: function, groovy, jenkins

I'm using the following code in **post-build** step of my Jenkins job:

```
evaluate(new File("Set-BuildBadge.groovy"));
```

So it runs a script successfully if it does **not** contain functions.

If inside the script I define a **function** for example:

```
def addSummaryWithText(Icon, Text) {
    manager.createSummary(Icon).appendText(Text, false)
}
...
addSummaryWithText("installer.gif", "Project: " + ProjectName)
```

then I get the following error:

> FATAL: Illegal class name "Set-BuildBadge$addSummaryWithText" in class
>   file Set-BuildBadge$addSummaryWithText java.lang.ClassFormatError:
>   Illegal class name "Set-BuildBadge$addSummaryWithText" in class file
>   Set-BuildBadge$addSummaryWithText     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ...

I'm not getting how **GroovyShell.evaluate** works.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you try without a hyphen in the script name?

Comment: Genious! I've lost 3 hours digging into groovy (new to me) and solution was just to remove hypen )))

Comment: added as an answer! :-)  Glad it's resolved!  Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! Awesome reputation by the way...

Comment: Haha, no worries!  And ta...not sure if it's a good thing, or a sign of some mild underlying addiction ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like the JVM doesn't like class names with a hyphen in them.

By calling your script `Set-BuildBadge.groovy` internally it is compiled into a class that isn't allowed when you add a function to the script.

Changing the name of the script to `SetBuildBadge.groovy` will fix it :-)