# Why is this an "illegal class name" in Groovy / Java?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, groovy

I am in a development environment constrained to Java JDK 1.8 (I have 1.8.0_111, specifically) and Groovy 2.1.9. I am developing in IntelliJ on MacOS, although the rest of the team operates the same via Windows. For reasons that we cannot discern, the following Groovy code runs fine on their setups but returns an "illegal class name" error for me. IntelliJ claims that `getFTPFileList`, `downloadFile`, and `getFTPSClient` are undefined and unused. The code itself is testing an FTPS connection to get .txt files.

Error

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "lvm-test$getFTPFileList" in class file lvm-test$getFTPFileList
About to connect...
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "lvm-test$getFTPFileList" in class file lvm-test$getFTPFileList
    at lvm-test.run(lvm-test.groovy:16)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Test Code

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*

// Configurable Constants
def fileDirectory = 'file/path/directory/'

//****************************************************************
// -- Process File retrieved from FTP --

// Connection alert
println "About to connect..."

def filenameOnly = ""

// Collect all files from FTP into an array
FTPFile[] files = getFTPFileList(fileDirectory)

// Cycle through array and process each file
for (FTPFile file : files) {
    // Validate: file size is greater than zero and is a text file
    if (file.getSize() > 0) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            // Set file name to name only, remove file ext suffix
            filenameOnly = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf(".txt"))

            // Download the .txt file
            ByteArrayOutputStream txtStream = downloadFile(filenameOnly + ".txt", FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE)
            boolean txtSuccess = (txtStream != null)
            if (txtStream) {
                println("File $filenameOnly .txt was successfully downloaded")
            }
        }
    }
}


//****************************************************************
// Get the list of files on the FTP server in the folder passed.
//****************************************************************
FTPFile[] getFTPFileList(String folder) {

    FTPFile[] fileList = null;
    FTPSClient ftpClient = getFTPSClient(folder);

    ftpClient.with {
        fileList = it.listFiles();
        disconnect();
    }
    return fileList;
}

//****************************************************************
//  Download file from FTP server in the folder passed.
// ****************************************************************
def downloadFile(String filename, int fileType) {

    println("Downloading $filename from FTP Server")
    FTPSClient ftpClient = getFTPSClient(fileDirectory);

    ByteArrayOutputStream fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    boolean bStream = false;

    ftpClient.with {
        setFileType(fileType);

        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream);
        bStream = it.retrieveFile(filename, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        disconnect();
    }

    if (bStream) {
        return fileStream;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

//****************************************************************
//  Return FTP Client to be used in this script
//****************************************************************
FTPSClient getFTPSClient(String workingFolder) {

    def host = "ftp.website.com"
    def usr = "username"
    def pwd = "password"

    FTPSClient ftpsClient = new FTPSClient()

    ftpsClient.with {
        connect(host)
        enterLocalPassiveMode()
        login(usr, pwd)
        changeToParentDirectory()
        changeWorkingDirectory(workingFolder)
        setConnectTimeout(3600000)
        setControlKeepAliveTimeout(3600000)
    }
    return ftpsClient
}

println("...Connected to FTP.");
```

Failed Solution #1: Attempted to convert all declaration to `def`. Neither worked.

```
FTPFile[] files = getFTPFileList(fileDirectory)
```

-->`def FTPFile[] files = getFTPFileList(fileDirectory)`
or
-->`def files = getFTPFileList(fileDirectory)`

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22839352/335858). I am not sure, though, so I wouldn't vote to close until you confirm this one way or the other.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm familiar enough with Groovy scripting to hammer it. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: ...can you explain how/why it is duplicate?

Comment: Read the accepted answer.  A hyphen is not allowed in a class name.  Find out where the hyphen is coming from, and you are 90% to solving the problem.  Hint: the problem isn't in your source code ...